# how to pass value from one jsp page to another without appending into url

Tags: jsp, jquery

i mates iam trying to pass value from one page to another jsp page without appending to url but iam unable to do so. So please help me out. This what i have done

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:'user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&Admin=a',
        url: "jsp/admin/master/Connectteacher.jsp",
        async: false,
         cache: false,
        success: function(check) {
if ($.trim(check) == 'block') {
                    window.location.replace("jsp/admin/master/Blockuser.jsp?name="+user+"&BlockA=a");
                  // $.post( "jsp/admin/master/Blockuser.jsp", { name: user, BlockA: "a"} );
                      }
```

i unable to figure it out, that how can i pass value to Blockuser.jsp without appending to url. $.post() not actually take me to that page.

Comment: Use cookies or webstorage.  You can't set post value for a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `session.setAttribute()` and `session.getAttributes()` for passing values from one jsp to another.

In one page do `session.setAttribute("test","test");` To retrieve this value in the other page
do `session.getAttribute("test");`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `session` as described by javaBeginner.

you can also create a from on the fly and submit it.

write a function similar to this one and use it in your success:

```
function submitValues(url, params) {
    var form = [ '<form method="POST" action="', url, '">' ];

    for(var key in params) 
        form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');

    form.push('</form>');

    jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit();
}
```